# A matrix with entries in ED is invertible if and only if the matrix can be row reduced to the identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> A matrix with entries in an Euclidean Domain is invertible if and only if the matrix can be row reduced to the identity matrix.
>
> Is the above statement true?

Comment: Any references of your "theorem"?

Comment: @Xam It is not a theorem though. I just want to know if this statement works under Euclidean domain since it works in basic linear algebra.

Comment: HINT: The only problem is that at each step of the Gaussian elimination, the considered element in the diagonal is not a divisor of the elements below. Now, encoding the Euclidean algorithm for calculating the greatest common divisor, this problem can be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Smith normal form for Euclidean domains, for any given matrix $ X $, there is $ A $ and $ B $; both products of matrices corresponding to invertible elementary row/column operations, such that $ X = ADB $ for a diagonal matrix $ D $. (Stated this way, the Smith normal form relies essentially on the Euclidean algorithm, so is not true for general principal ideal domains.) If $ X $ is invertible, it follows that the nonzero entries of $ D $ are all units, which we may wlog assume to be $ 1 $. Therefore; $ X = AB = (AB)I $, where $ AB $ is a product of matrices corresponding to invertible elementary row operations, and therefore $ (AB)^{-1} X = I $. Thus, the answer to the question is positive.

Things are not as trivial as [Josué Tonelli-Cueto](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15330/josu%C3%A9-tonelli-cueto) surmises in the comments; as using the Euclidean algorithm during row reduction may cause elements which have been reduced to zero to become nonzero again. The Smith normal form, however, gives a straightforward way of answering the question. (Note that the algorithm for producing the Smith normal form also allows for *column reduction*, so the problems we may run into are resolved more easily.)